# Proof that inequality of curvature leads to an inequality of the arc-length for two smooth curves.

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, arc-length

Let $\alpha_1:[0,l_1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, \alpha_2:[0,l_2]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be two smooth closed curves parametrized by arc-length such that $\alpha_i|_{[0,l_i)}$ is injective and that $\alpha^{\prime}_i(l_i)=\alpha_i^{\prime}(0)$, for each $i=1,2$. Suppose that the (signed) curcature $k_i(s)$ of $\alpha_i$ satisfies $k_i(s) > 0$ for all $s \in [0, l_i]$, and that $k_1(s) \geq k_2(s)$ for all $s \in [0, \min{(l_1, l_2)}]$.

Prove that $l_1 \leq l_2$.

Intuatively this seem clear. However I am struggling to find a proof. 
Any help whould be appreciated.

Comment: One can use the fact $\int_{\alpha} \kappa(s) ds=2\pi$, where $s$ is the arclength parameter. So if $\kappa$ is bigger, the integral interval must be shorter.

Comment: Thank you that was helpfull